# How do I determine what running process is using java?

Tags: linux

I'm looking at the 'top' output on my linux server.  I see that the command 'java' is taking up a lot of memory.  How can I use this PID, etc. to see what process actually started up the jvm?

Also, is this process actually the jvm or just some generic command?

Ultimately I just want a way to see more information about this command/process instead of just 'java.'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use ps command to get extended information about command which launched process:

```
ps -fp <pid>
```

Also you could take information of every java process with ps:

```
ps -ef | grep java | grep -v grep
```

Comment: Excellent.  Works like a charm!

Comment: Just FYI, I also looked through the manpage for 'top' and found that using 'c' will toggle between the 'command line' (default) and 'program name.'  So, in my case when looking at 'top' I can hit 'c' and see the name of the application.

Comment: You can also use the `pstree` command to get a more visual representation of process parent child relationships.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `jps` and `jcmd` Java utilities to display running Java processes. Explore their options to find out more about they can provide.